# How can I pass URI using explicit intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to use an explit intent to launch a particular number on a softphone app. 
An implicit app would look like:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phone));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

The launch of an explicit app something looks like:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("example.app");
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Question: Is it possible to pass Uri and start the app with ACTION_CALL using an explicit intent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Using your example, you can do this:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("example.app");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(phone));
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

When you use an explicit `Intent`, Android doesn't use the ACTION or DATA fields in the `Intent` to determine which `Activity` to start. You have already set that explicitly in the `Intent`. But you can still set the ACTION and DATA fields in the `Intent` to pass information to the `Activity` you are starting.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. Strange thing is, that this works fine when using skype but not with other apps. If I use "com.skype.raider" as package-name and specify "tel:123456" as URI this works great. But when I use other softphone apps it doesn't, although the documnentation clearly specifies the URI ("sip:account@server.com"). Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: It is possible that the other application uses the ACTION and DATA to start a **different Activity** than the one that it uses to **launch the application**. To find out, you can either try launching the app with implicit Intent and see which Activity gets started, or you can query the PackageManager to find out which Activities can resolve the ACTION and DATA you are using.